# Format code within <pre> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, prettify

I'm trying to make something, so you fill out a form, press a button, and it generates code below it with whatever you input in the appropriate place.

I've been given dozens of "template codes" which will have 2 or 3 words in it change, depending on the user input.

however, i have these in pre tags, so instead of putting things in `<` or `>` I need to type `&lt;` or `&gt;`, which means if I try and get anything to format it for me (put indents and stuff) it does it wrong.

Can someone tell me how to format it using something like prettify?

Comment: Why dont use mentioned pretiffy?

Comment: @Kasyx : prettify will syntax highlight. But wont do indentation.